# Como exibir a url de navegação anterior com PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Pessoal utilizo a função abaixo para ir para a próxima pergunta de um sistema de perguntas que tenho,não consegui criar essa função para voltar,alguém teria alguma dica?

Botão:

```
  echo"<button id='button' type='next' name='next' class='btn btn-danger'>
                      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right'></span>Próxima</button><br />";
```

Função:

```
 if(isset($_GET['proxima'])){
    $pergunta = (int)$_GET['proxima'];
    header('location: comportamento.php?nro_pergunta='.$pergunta);  
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez a solução seja uma coisa bem simples, como no caso abaixo, utilizando `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">Voltar</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

### Atualização

Como sugerido nos comentários, opcionalmente, você pode checar se a origem é do mesmo site. Você pode usar a função `parse_url` para extrair apenas o domínio.

```
$host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER', PHP_URL_HOST);

if ($host === 'exemplo.com.br') {
  // Lógica se for o mesmo domínio
}
```

Comment: E se ele quiser, ainda pode verificar se o REFERER é do mesmo site, pra habilitar o botão.

Comment: @Wallace Maxters  , deu certo obrigado.

Comment: @Bacco , deu certo obrigado.