# "Referer" ou "Referrer"? Isso é algum erro ortográfico ou está correto?

Tags: php, javascript, terminologia

Sinceramente, estou com uma dúvida tremenda agora. Acabei de dar essa resposta aqui no stackoverflow:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123445/4995

Nessa resposta, eu ensino que, para me referir à página anterior, devemos usar a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Eu até fiz testes antes, pois, como de costume sempre me questiono se é com uma ou duas letras `R`;

A minha confusão aumentou quando me deparei com isso no `Javascript`:

```
 document.referrer; // What? Com dois R?
```

E sei que as duas coisas, tanto do PHP como a do Javascript, servem para referir-se à página anterior.

Então, confuso, gostaria de saber:
O certo é refe**R**er ou refe**RR**er (com um ou dois R)?

Comment: Antes de julgarem como fora de escopo, é importante pelo menos saber a diferença entre um e outro  (se não for algum tipo de erro, é claro).;

Comment: Acho uma duvida bem valida, eu mesmo nunca havia notado o erro de ortografia.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

É um erro ortográfico na especificação do protocolo HTTP que foi mantido por uso.

> O referer, ou HTTP referer (é escrito erroneamente como referer nas especificações HTTP oficiais e padronizado assim desde então) é um campo de cabeçalho HTTP que identifica o endereço da página web.

[O erro foi cometido por Phillip Hallam-Baker e Roy Fielding em 1992](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!original/alt.folklore.computers/7X75In21_54/JgV9Rw04f-EJ). Quando eles notaram o erro ortográfico já existiam muitas implementações que utilizavam o código, e ele não poderia ser alterado.

Correções ortográficas são geralmente feitas em outras camadas, como no caso do PHP. Já em Javascript o valor interpretado é corretamente carregado em *document.referrer*.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).

Comment: Para terminar de **cagar**, o PHP me faz uma dessa. Realmente, não sabia dessa informações.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é o PHP que faz isto, as variaveis `HTTP_` no PHP são geradas automaticamente e obtidas dos Headers enviados, o php pega todos os headers e adiciona o prefixo `HTTP_`, quem enviou assim `Referer:` foi o browser :)

Comment: Ah, entendi. Ufa, menos uma cagada para o PHP então.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters *Dessa vez* a culpa não é do PHP. ;)

Comment: @OnoSendai não sei se é importante citar na pergunta, mas essa diferença então entre as duas linguagens, é porque o `HTTP_REFERER` vem dos headers do browser, e não uma funcionalidade específica da linguagem.,