# Origem - Midia do visitante

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Sei que é possivel pegar a url anterior do visitante com `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` mas como faço para por exemplo pegar a origem/midia que o visitante estava antes de acessar o site?

Por exemplo se veio do: Google/Organic, Google/CPC (pago), Bing/Organic, Bing/CPC, Direct/none, facebook/referral, youtube/referral, outros sites/referral, etc .

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: O que você chama de "origem/midia" que não consta do [referrer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123468/70)?

Comment: @Bacco obrigada pela contribuição. Encontrei a solução, criei uma resposta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução no GitHub: [Google Analytics Cookie Parser PHP](https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP/blob/master/tests/GACookie/UtmzTest.php)

Basicamente devo realizar o parser de alguns cookies do Google Analytics, por exemplo o `utma` e o `umtz`, e acessar as informações que preciso

**Para utma**

```
$utma->time_of_first_visit; // DateTime
$utma->time_of_last_visit; // DateTime
$utma->time_of_current_visit; // DateTime
$utma->session_count // Integer
```

**For utmz**

```
$utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
$utmz->session_count // Integer
$utmz->campaign_number // Integer
$utmz->source // string
$utmz->medium // string
$utmz->campaign // string
$utmz->term // string
$utmz->content // string
```