# Pegar URL e passar para a próxima página

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Já tentei de diversas maneiras, preciso pegar o valor da URL atual, e passar para a próxima página, para que após a ação do criar for concluída, eu volte para a URL que foi passada, como posso proceder? 
Obrigado.

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

if (urlAnterior.Contains("Pagina"))
    return RedirectToAction("");
else
    return RedirectToAction("");
```

E também assim:

```
 string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    if (urlAnterior.Contains("Pessoa"))
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pessoa");
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ContaReceber");
```

Porém nenhuma das duas funcionou, queria salvar a URL em uma variável por exemplo, e passar para a próxima página, assim ele saberia corretamente, para onde deve voltar.

EDIT:

Aqui é onde eu chamo a página create de contas a receber, passando o parâmetro id da pessoa que está no edit.

```
<a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Create" asp-route-id="@Request.Query["id"]" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Criar nova Conta</a>
```

Comment: Como você esta tentando fazer?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Não há a possibilidade de utilizar o cabeçalho HTTP REFERER?

Comment: Sou recente na linguagem, como assim cabeçalho HTTP REFERER? Se puder me auxiliar.

Comment: Você que voltar para uma página anterior da mesma controller ?

Comment: Eu tenho a página CREATE de Contas a Receber, esta página pode ser chamada dentro do edit de pessoas, ou então do INDEX de Contas a Receber, eu quero que ela volte, de onde ela foi chamada.

Comment: O Cabecalho `http_referer` (sim, é escrito "referer" e não "referrer"  porque o abençoado que criou isso errou o nome) serve para obter a url anterior (ou de origem) de uma requisição. Quando você abre a página diretamente (ou faz um show de redirecionamentos), obviamente não terá nada relevante no HTTP_REFERER

Comment: A título da curiosidade: [Referer ou Referrer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123468)

Comment: a titulo de gambiara você também pode recebe sua URL como parâmetro da sua action CREATE (get) e armazenar em um TempData e no POST  do CREATE só recuperar a variavel TempData ...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters então no meu caso eu não consigo utilizar o http referer? É isto ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, no caso do create, se ele for chamado em pessoas eu já passo um parâmetro, eu passaria junto ? É isto? Vou colocar na pergunta, como que eu chamo em pessoas.

Comment: Jovem, @marianac_costa, já pensou em passar a `url` que quer como parâmetro no GET? (fiz isso ontem numa implementação aqui)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu editei a pergunta com a parte que eu já passo um parâmetro, como eu passaria no caso a url ? Desculpe, ainda estou aprendendo esta linguagem.

Comment: @marianac_costa atente-se ao que está utilizando da ferramenta para não utilizar errado. O *snippet* de código (`</>`) são para exemplos completos em HTML/JS/CSS. Para **qualquer** outra coisa, utilize o botão `{}`, ou apenas indente o código com 4 espaços na pergunta. Mesmo que seja apenas HTML, CSS ou JS que **não há o que executar**, não utilize o *snippet*. Dica: qualquer outra linguagem dessas, utilize `{}`.

Comment: @marianac_costa, você tentou UrlReferrer ? É uma propriedade que retorna justamente a url anterior. Observe a minha resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar UrlReferrer para obter a url anterior.

```
    //ASP.NET MVC 5
    public ActionResult SuaAction()
    {
        string urlAnterior = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        Response.Redirect(urlAnterior); //Redireciona pra url anterior.

        return View();
    }

    //ASP.NET MVC CORE
    public IActionResult SuaAction()
    {
        string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString(); 
        Response.Redirect(urlAnterior); //Redireciona pra url anterior.

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente desta forma, e ele me retorna a url atual, ele está retornando: { http://localhost:55695/ContaReceber/Create?id=2 }, que no caso é a página que eu passo quando clico em criar, dentro de pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível saída: ao chamar a Action /ContaReceber/Create, passe um parâmetro adicional chamado returnUrl, que é a URL atual:

- Na sua classe Startup, no método ConfigureServices, adicione a linha:

  ```
  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
  ```
- No seu Controller, adicione a propriedade para IHttpContextAcessor e receba no controller:

  ```
  private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
  public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
      this._acessor = accessor;
  }
  ```
- Agora no seu método, você pode acessar a URL atual:

  `var url = _accessor.HttpContext?.Request?.GetDisplayUrl();`
- No método em que você pega a URL atual, use o RedirectToAction passando o parâmetro:

  `public IActionResult Index(string returnUrl = "") {
      ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
  }`

Pronto, agora na view da Action ContaReceber, você pode acessar no Razor a url passada, com o @ViewBag.ReturnUrl e criar um botão para retornar a página anterior.

Comment: Eu gostaria que ele redirecionasse automaticamente após o create, no caso um if, e ele mesmo redirecione, não um button que volte para a página anterior.

Comment: Então você dá um Redirect(returnUrl);

Comment: Eu utilizo asp.net core, public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) { não entendi, e ele utiliza o próprio controller da página.

Comment: É para você colocar o construtor do controller que vai chamar a página de criação, como não sei o nome das suas classes, coloquei Controller. Caso você já tenha um construtor, somente adicione o parâmetro.

Comment: Não consegui, pensei em fazer desta maneira, return RedirectToPage("./Pessoa/Edit?id=" + id); porém ele me retorna erro.