# Salvar a origem de tráfego do usuário

Tags: php, html, input

Preciso salvar a origem de tráfego de usuário. Como a URL do post é diferente da URL do formulário, estou utilizando um input hidden no formulário para resgatar esse dado (se não, a origem de tráfego sempre será a URL do formulário).
Porém, não estou conseguindo resgatar esse dado pelo value no input (o dado vem sempre vazio).

A ideia é saber por qual página ele entrou no formulário (antes de submetê-lo).

Código:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" id="origem" name="origem">
```

Comment: E por que não usa `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` direto no servidor? Usar isso num `input[type=hidden]` é totalmente inviável. O usuário pode manipular os dados do seu relátorio a vontade se ele abrir o F12 do Google Chrome!

Comment: O problema é que, conforme descrito, a URL é diferente. Quando se utiliza esse código diretamente no servidor, ele resgata a URL do formulário sempre.

Comment: Então salve na sessão. A solução não é colocar no formulário, cara. Não é seguro, o usuário poderia alterar isso, entende?

Comment: Se bem de que qualquer forma, quem manipula o formulário poderia manipular o `header` também. Você está usando o formulário em mais de uma página, é isso?

Comment: Como assim na sessão?

Comment: Esse formulário, em específico, estou utilizando apenas em uma página.

Comment: Entendi. O `HTTP_REFERER` então seria pra saber por qual página ele entrou no formulário (antes de submetê-lo)?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente isso.

Comment: @EduardoMartinsCasagrande Caso você queira a origem apenas dentro do seu site, você pode salvar o conteúdo da variável `location.href` em um *cookie*/*localStorage* ou você pode forçar um cabeçalho diferente, por exemplo: `X-HTTP-REFER`.  **Ps.:** Por questões de segurança, [os navegadores *podem* alterar o valor do cabeçalho](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

> Porém, não estou conseguindo resgatar esse dado pelo value no input (o dado vem sempre vazio).

Geralmente, quando você abre a página diretamente pelo barra do navegador, não é gerado o header `HTTP_REFERER`.
Isso porque o `referrer` se refere a uma página de origem. Ou seja, se você veio de uma página para outra.

Eu sugiro que, para colocar um valor padrão no `HTTP_REFERER` caso não exista nada, você possa colocar assim:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="origem" name="origem">
```

> se não, a origem de tráfego sempre será a URL do formulário)

No caso do `PHP_SELF`, você poderia colocar outro valor, que seria o valor padrão caso não existisse nada no `HTTP_REFERER`. Você poderia cadastrá-lo manualmente, mas creio que `PHP_SELF` já se encarrega bem desse trabalho.

## Já pensou em usar sessão?

Supondo que o usuário pode manipular essa informação, eu sugiro que você use `$_SESSION` para armazenar a `HTTP_REFERER`, caso ela existir.

Por exemplo:

```
// script_do_formulario.php

session_start();

// Se o header referer existir, ele vai ser adicionado na sessão, 
// e não vai sair, ao menos que o usuário entre na página novamente.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
       $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Na hora de salvar os dados do formulário, você vai verificar se o valor de   `$_SESSION['referrer']` existe para salvá-lo no banco.

## Curiosidades

Apenas a título de curiosidade, você pode estar confuso sobre ser "referer" ou "referrer" (com dois "r"). Tem uma pergunta sobre isso aqui:

- ["Referer" ou "Referrer"? Isso é algum erro ortográfico ou está correto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123468/referer-ou-referrer-isso-%C3%A9-algum-erro-ortogr%C3%A1fico-ou-est%C3%A1-correto)

Comment: Complemento: [Segurança e Privacidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) **e** [Divulgação de informações confidenciais em URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-9.4)

Comment: No caso, eu estou vindo da página inicial do site, então, a origem deveria ser a URL da página inicial, certo? Porém, o código que escrito dentro value do input parece ser ignorado, porque o mesmo sempre vem como um índice vazio.

Comment: Obrigado @ValdeirPsr. Era algo sobre segurança que queria alertá-lo antes. O usuário poderia mexer nessas alterações facilmente se fosse input. Mas o link que você mandou aí é ainda mais sério, kkkkkkk.

Comment: @EduardoMartinsCasagrande Se tiver um redirect no meio do caminho, o `referer` não vai funcionar.