# Como é criado o escopo de um event listener definido em algum atributo no HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, atributos

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handlers_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value), quando o *listener* de evento é atribuído como um atributo HTML, o código especificado (no valor do atributo) é envolvido em uma função, com os seguintes parâmetros:

- `event` — para todos os atributos, exceto `onerror`;
- `event`, `source`, `lineno`, `colno`, e `error` — para `onerror`.

O `this` da função é definido como o elemento HTML que contém o atributo de evento.

---

No entanto, uma outra pergunta aqui no SOpt (agora apagada<sup>[[1]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/483690/69296)</sup>) me deixou curioso porque acessa a variável `value` dentro de um desses *attribute handlers*. Assim:

```html
<input onkeyup="console.log(value)" />
```

Verificando se existe um argumento a mais, para a minha surpresa, não. Realmente, conforme colocou a documentação, somente `event` é passado (já que se trata de um *event attribute* que não é `onerror`):

```html
<input onkeyup="console.log([...arguments])" />

<!-- Escondi o console do snippet porque são muitas propriedades.
     Abra e veja no próprio console do navegador. -->
```

Após maiores investigações, percebi que todas as propriedades de [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/target) também estão no escopo. Saliento que `value` é uma propriedade desse objeto.

Então me parece que há algo como um `with(event.target)` em algum lugar, mas isso é uma suposição e não há confirmação. É, sem dúvidas, detalhe de implementação, já que a exposição desses valores pode ser feita de outro modo. O problema é que, vendo o *source* da função executada, não há nada além do parâmetro `event`:

```html
<input onkeyup="console.log(arguments.callee.toString())" />
```

Pergunto:

- Como isso acontece (como é criado o escopo desse *attribute event listener*)?
- Isso está especificado?
- Além de (aparentemente) todas as propriedades de `Event.target` estarem disponíveis, posso acessar mais algum valor?
- Qual o suporte disso nos navegadores?

Comment: Creio que **isso seja como usar o `this`** aonde qualquer o objeto é o elemento DOM e os eventos são partes da interface "estendida", logo `value` é o mesmo que chamar `this.value`, para um teste rápido `<input onkeyup="console.log(this)" />`, outro teste com uma propriedade de um objeto Element `<input onkeyup="console.log(tagName)" />` ou `<input onkeyup="console.log(outerHTML)" />`, resumindo, esse é o comportamento natural em diversas interfaces usadas em JS, já o `arguments` e `Event` não tem haver com o objeto diretamente sobre o teste com `onkeyup="console.log(value)"`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o problema é que aí o acesso teria que ser explícito `this.value`, por exemplo. Se fizer `(function() { console.log(value); }).call({ value: 50 })` dará erro. Ainda mantenho a pergunta principal de como esse acesso "implícito" é possível. E eu sei que o `arguments` não tem a ver com isso, utilizei-o somente para fins de demonstração.

Comment: Não, porque você esta confundindo o comportamento "dentro do HTML", nele o **`this`** pode ser **"implícito"**, não é algo absoluto JavaScript, é do "HTML" (note as aspas). Não estou citando fonte técnica e nem especificação de linguagem, o teste é prático, o "implícito" só quer dizer que em HTML (dependendo de como usa nos atributos `*on`) o `this` ***não precisará ser escrito*** (ou seja esta "implícito")

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, procurei por referências, mas não encontrei motivos para entender que o comportamento do JavaScript mudaria dentro do atributo. Na minha concepção, se, dentro do atributo, código JavaScript é executado, então há de rodar seguindo as "regras do JS". Por isso a dúvida — o `this`, no JS, não é implícito (como você sabe), então ainda não consigo explicar ao certo. Aparentemente, realmente as propriedades do `this` são "espalhados" para o escopo do _attribute listener_, mas ainda não encontrei referência para isso. Você tem alguma fonte que corrobore essa sua última afirmação?

Comment: Ok, vou lhes adiantar, tem muita coisa que veio no HTML e JavaScript (esse por sinal da Mozilla, os demais são dialetos "semelhantes/quase identicos") que só começaram a ser DOCUMENTADAS e padronizadas depois, os comportamentos no geral foram apenas sendo copiados entre os concorrentes, desde o surgimento do JavaScript (e na microsoft o JScript), só uns poucos anos depois veio a ter o "ECMAScript", o w3.org já existia, mas não foram eles que definiram inicialmente o comportamentos do JavaScript, já que esse veio depois do HTML já existir ...

Comment: ... então uma coisa lhes garanto, não existem organização perfeita, muitas coisas vão sendo arrumadas ou documentadas depois, eu posso até encontrar alguma referencia no https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-handler-content-attributes, mas provavelmente será vago (mesmo que cite coisas mais especificas como o CSP), não quer dizer que vamos encontrar tudo bonitinho e bem escrito ou determinado que é regra, as empresas ficaram se copiando e coisas até mesmo "desnecessárias" existem por causa disso ...

Comment: ... inclusive erro de gramática em uma propriedade do Document em JS: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123468/3635, então é provavel que eu não possa fornecer respostas "documentadas" de tudo, o que posso afirmar são com testes, que já citei no primeiro comentário, `this` é "implícito" em atributos HTML "on", assim como funções e variaveis globais também serão, isso foram testes que fiz, em diferentes navegadores, inclusive navegadores antigos. **É o que posso responder por hora, nem tudo em TI é feito ou planejado a perfeição. ;)**

Comment: Também já tinha encontrado esse mesmo trecho no _HTML Standard_, mas realmente é vago. De todo modo, continuo a procurar por uma referência (e também esperando por alguma resposta concreta, no caso de alguém a encontrar). Obrigado pelos comentários. :-)

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente a motivação, ainda sim espero que tenha dado atenção a histórinha sobre o JavaScript ser da Mozilla, antes de se juntarem a "ECMA International" e que outros navegadores (no caso o IE) tinha apenas um dialeto extremamente semelhante, então as coisas foram sendo "copiadas" de ambos lados, por isso espere achar muita coisa além, o que pode lhe confirmar algo talvez seria olhar os **códigos fonte** do Chromium https://github.com/chromium/chromium e FF: https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

O elemento que contém o *attribute listener* é usado para derivar o escopo da função que será executada. Por isso que as propriedades do elemento (como `textContent`, `value` etc) podem ser acessadas diretamente — porque fazem, literalmente, parte do **escopo** da função.

<sub>Ressalto que esta resposta vale somente para *attribute event handlers* (isto é, aqueles definidos diretamente em atributos no HTML). Eventos adicionados via `addEventListener` funcionam (similarmente) de outro jeito. Não há modificação do escopo da função passada ao segundo argumento de `addEventListener`.</sub>

---

Cada evento a ser ouvido no navegador possui um *struct* associado, chamado `Event Handler`<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes)</sup>, que contém um campo `listener` (que corresponde ao *ouvidor* de eventos) e outro campo, `value`. No caso dos eventos adicionados através de atributos no HTML, o `value` desse *struct* corresponde ao que a especificação chama de *internal raw uncompiled handler*.

Esse *internal raw uncompiled handler* é uma tupla contém as seguintes informações: <sup>[[2]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler)</sup>

- O corpo do script (não compilado — "*uncompiled*"), que é o código que está inserido no valor do atributo.
- A localização de onde o script se originou, no caso de um erro precisar ser reportado.

Uma vez que o *listener* é acionado, o navegador procede à avaliação (compilação) do script, que será utilizado para a criação da função `callback` (que será executada). Para a criação dessa função, leva-se em conta [este algoritmo <sup>[3]</sup>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm), que faz uso da operação interna [`OrdinaryFunctionCreate`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryfunctioncreate) (do ECMAScript).

A `OrdinaryFunctionCreate` é uma operação interna do ECMAScript com a seguinte assinatura:

```
OrdinaryFunctionCreate (functionPrototype, ParameterList, Body, thisMode, Scope)
```

Ela é usada para criar a função `callback`. Para isso, os seguintes argumentos são passados:

- `functionPrototype` ⇒ é o `Function.prototype` (já somos familiarizados com esse protótipo com as outras funções do JavaScript, que também o assumem).
- `ParameterList` ⇒ no caso de eventos que não são erros (como `onclick`, `onkeydown` etc), corresponde a `event`.
- `Body` ⇒ o corpo da função é gerado dinamicamente através de concatenações com o nome do evento e o corpo. É, basicamente:

  ```
  function <<name>>(event) {
  <<body>>
  }
  ```

  <sup>Em que `<<name>>` é o nome da função *callback* associada ao evento (como `onclick`) e `<<body>>` é o código JavaScript adicionado no atributo de evento no HTML.</sup>
- `thisMode` ⇒ passa-se "*non-lexical-this*".
- `Scope` ⇒ O escopo é definido da seguinte forma:

  - Inicialmente, o escopo o objeto `document`;
  - Se o elemento que possui o *attribute event listener* está dentro de um formulário (possui um *form owner*), o objeto do formulário **também** é incorporado ao ecopo;
  - Se o elemento que possui o *attribute event listener* é não nulo, o objeto desse elemento **também** é incorporado ao escopo.

Desse modo, pode-se afirmar que o escopo surge através dessa tripla derivação (`document → form owner → eventTarget`). Por isso que, inteiramente, o escopo não será igual ao `this`.

Consulte o [algoritmo completo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm) para saber mais.

Uma vez que a função `callback` esteja criada, ela é executada. Para essa invocação, o `this` é definido como o elemento que contém o *event attribute*<sup>[[4]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm)</sup>.

---

### Conclusão

Concluímos, portanto, que valores como `value`, `textContent` (e todas as outras propriedades presentes no elemento que ativou o evento) são acessíveis "diretamente" desse jeito pois estão **escopo** da função `callback` criada pelo navegador. O [conceito de escopo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) é explicado na MDN.

Não confundir escopo com [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), que, a grosso modo, é apenas mais um nome do escopo de uma função.

Mesmo se o "`this` implícito" fosse possível em JavaScript ([o que não é](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875950/7445826)), o exemplo a seguir demonstra o porquê desse não ser o caso (há uma diferença entre o `this` e o valor do escopo):

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="
    console.log({
      this_elements: typeof this.elements,   // undefined
      scoped_elements: typeof elements,      // object
      
      are_eql: this.elements === elements    // false
    })
  ">
    Clique
  </button>
</form>


    <h3>Explicação</h3>
    Mesmo que fosse possível em JavaScript, o "<code>this</code>
    implícito" não poderia ocorrer nessa situação, já que há uma
    evidente (demonstrada acima) diferença de valores.

    O escopo da função, criado a partir do documento, formulário
    pai (se presente) e, enfim elemento associado ao
    <em>attribute event</em>, é diferente do <code>this</code>
    da função, que corresponde (ao contrário do escopo)
    unicamente ao elemento associado ao <em>attribute event</em>.
```

Isso acontece porque, quando a função *callback* (criada conforme expliquei acima) é invocada, seu `this` é definido como o elemento que contém o *attribute event listener*. Já o escopo (definido durante a criação dessa função *callback*) é criado a partir da derivação do objeto `document`, do *form owner* (se presente) e do próprio elemento referente ao evento. *São, pois, diferentes.*

---

> Como isso acontece?

Explicado acima.

> Isso está especificado?

Sim. As referências para a especificação estão no texto.

> Além de (aparentemente) todas as propriedades de `Event.target` estarem disponíveis, posso acessar mais algum valor?

Na verdade (ao contrário do que eu inicialmente pensei), não é o `event.target` que é "colocado" como escopo, mas sim o elemento que contém o *event attribute* (o elemento associado ao evento). O `event.target` [nem sempre a ele corresponderá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/7445826).

> Qual o suporte disso nos navegadores?

Os navegadores que seguem a especificação implementam isso e, portanto, suportam o que aqui foi discutido. A implementação varia entre *host*, já que a especificação não se preocupa em ditar *como fazer*, mas sim *o que fazer*.

---

### Referência

- [ECMAScript® 2020 Language Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html)
- [Seção "*Events*" do *HTML Standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#events)
- [Why is there no implicit this in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875950/7445826)

Comment: Só pra constar, `OrdinaryFunctionCreate` traduzido seria como **"criar uma função qualquer/normal"**, então ele esta na especificação, não quer dizer que é esse nome em motores javascript que rodam em navegadores nem quer dizer que será exatamente assim que o motor funciona, o que precisa é ele atender a isso, mas não ser exatamente isso. E vale ressaltar que referir-se ao this naquele momento queria mais dizer, se comporta como tal, não quer dizer que internamente é exatamente isso.

Comment: Deem uma olhada [nessa modificação](https://jsfiddle.net/4qengm51/) do código de origem. Em `<input type="button" value="Duplicar" onclick="botao( visor.value );" />` além do `this` estar implícito também é possível referenciar os outros elementos identificáveis no contexto do  `<form>`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, realmente. Isso também está descrito no [algoritmo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler) ([veja esta imagem com algumas marcações minhas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQc2B.png)). O que ocorre é que o escopo é definido, primeiramente, como o documento e, depois, no caso de formulários, incorpora-se ao elemento do formulário e, depois, ao próprio elemento que possui o _event attribute_. :-) Quanto ao `this` estar implícito, isso não acontece no JavaScript (conforme explica o último link, nas referências de minha resposta).

Comment: Nesse caso, a grossas palavras, trata-se de uma "derivação tripla do escopo" — `document → form owner → eventTarget`. :D