# Como fazer com que vários elementos participem do event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

Criei uma página com cards e adicionei um ícone FontAwesome em cada um. No entanto, quando tento fazer com que essa ação de repita nos demais cards, não funciona. Quando clico em qualquer outro card, apenas o primeiro obedece à função.

```js
var favBtn =  document.getElementById('button')

function clique() { 
  if (favBtn.classList.contains("far")) {
    favBtn.classList.remove("far")
    favBtn.classList.add("fas")
  } else {
    favBtn.classList.remove("fas")
    favBtn.classList.add("far")
  }
}
```

```html
<i onclick="clique()" id="button" class="far fa-star"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque, embora cada botão tenha um *attribute event listener*, todos eles executam a mesma função (no caso, a função `clique`). No entanto, repare que a função `clique` opera somente com o resultado de `document.getElementById('button')`. Isto é, irá trabalhar somente com o *primeiro* botão que tiver ID igual a `button`.

Ademais, [utilizar vários elementos com um mesmo ID não é uma boa prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318255/69296) no HTML. Se você precisar utilizar um seletor comum a vários elementos, prefira utilizar uma classe.

Nesse caso, você deveria permitir certo dinamismo aí, de modo a executar a função de acordo com o elemento que ativou o evento. Para isso, você pode passar o `this` como argumento à função, no atributo `onclick`. Assim:

```html
<!--               ↓↓↓↓                                    -->
<i onclick="clique(this)" id="button" class="far fa-star"></i>
```

Conforme expliquei em mais detalhes [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483751/69296), quando um atributo de evento é executado, o valor de `this` refere-se ao elemento que ativou o evento (nesse caso será sempre o elemento que possui o próprio *attribute event listener*). Assim, você pode acessar esse argumento como o primeiro parâmetro de `clique`:

```js
function clique(favBtn) { 
  if (favBtn.classList.contains("far")) {
    favBtn.classList.remove("far");
    favBtn.classList.add("fas");
  } else {
    favBtn.classList.remove("fas");
    favBtn.classList.add("far");
  }
}
```

Note que agora, ao invés de operar com um único botão, a função opera com o parâmetro que receberá (nesse caso, sempre será o próprio botão — que ativou o evento).

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
function clique(favBtn) { 
  if (favBtn.classList.contains("far")) {
    favBtn.classList.remove("far");
    favBtn.classList.add("fas");
  } else {
    favBtn.classList.remove("fas");
    favBtn.classList.add("far");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Ignore. Está aqui somente para diferenciar ao clique. */
.far { color: red; }
.fas { color: blue; }
```

```html
<i onclick="clique(this)" class="far fa-star">1</i>
<i onclick="clique(this)" class="far fa-star">2</i>
<i onclick="clique(this)" class="far fa-star">3</i>
```

Apenas como sugestão, esse código pode ser melhorado. Você pode manipular isso tudo utilizando o próprio JavaScript (utilizando o [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)). Pode utilizar o método [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle), implementado por `clasList` para evitar o `if`. Veja:

```js
// Selecionamos todos os botões (utilizamos a classe `rating-btn`):
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('rating-btn');

for (const btn of btns) {
  // Para cada botão (`btn`), adicionamos um listener de eventos:
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // O `this` aqui corresponde ao botão que foi clicado.
    
    this.classList.toggle('fas');
    this.classList.toggle('far');
  });
}
```

```css
/* Ignore. Está aqui somente para diferenciar ao clique. */
.far { color: red; }
.fas { color: blue; }
```

```html
<i class="rating-btn far fa-star">1</i>
<i class="rating-btn far fa-star">2</i>
<i class="rating-btn far fa-star">3</i>
```

---

<sup>Note também que adicionei ponto e vírgula ao final de cada *statement*. Sei que parece frescura, mas o ponto e vírgula pode ajudá-la a evitar diversos comportamentos estranhos, como [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/69296). Saiba mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/69296).</sup>

Comment: A quem deixou o negativo: por favor, queira justificar. Não consigo saber onde melhorar sem uma direção. Até onde vejo, a resposta está boa, embora aberta a sugestões. :-)